# How many Kings can you Achieve?

Tags: checkerboard, board-games

In a standard American game of checkers what's the maximum amount of kings a player can get, and what is the move sequence?

**Keeping in mind the force capture rule**

Comment: Dear god it's spread from chess to checkers. Not a puzzle imo

Comment: @Joe I would argue that this is a puzzle.

Comment: Puzzle: "a game, toy, or problem designed to test ingenuity or knowledge." Would you say this is not a problem, and that it does not test a solvers knowledge?

Comment: All of them? This seems pretty obvious.

Comment: @minitech How do you suppose you achieve all of them? What is the move sequence to get all the kings? Remember there *is* a **force capture** rule.

Comment: Depends on the pieces you play with.  If you have "reversable" pieces (e.g. where you can flip over to "king") then it is all of them (12). However if you have to "stack" 2 of your pieces together to get a "king" then the answer is half (6).

Comment: @warspyking: Maybe you should specify that there’s a force capture rule in your question.

Comment: @minitech I actually got an answer on another site now! Yay. Also force capture rule is a standard rule of checkers. I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Wait everyone - the pieces would get in the way of each other getting to the last rank. Get out a board and try it!

Comment: is it just one side? or total kings on board?

Comment: @d'alar'cop One side.

Comment: @Daniel If the opponent is extremely naive (or actually helping you out) they may end up providing ease of passage to the other side. e.g. when I play with a small child its amazing how quickly my pieces get jumped and they get king'd ;-)

Comment: "Solve for X" is also a problem, but that clearly belongs on Math.SE instead. "Is technically a puzzle" does not mean "is meaningfully a puzzle", and neither of those means "belongs on Puzzling". With that in mind, maybe this *is* a puzzle, but I don't find it very interesting.

Comment: I know the answer, but I'm wondering if my fellow puzzlers can figure it out :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following game produces $12$ kings on the black side.  I have suffixed the usual move with $K$ when a king is made:
$$\begin {array} {l l} 10-14&21-17\\ 14\text { x }21&22-17
\\9-13&25-22\\7-10&30-25\\
21\text { x }30K&17-14\\10\text { x }17&29-25\\
30\text { x }21&24-20\\21-25&20-16\\
11\text { x }20&22-18\\25-29&18-15\\
17-21&15-10\\6\text { x }15&26-22\\
21-25&22-18\\15\text { x }22&23-19\\
5-9&19-15\\1-5&31-26\\
22\text { x }31K&27-23\\25-30K&15-10\\
29-25&28-24\\20\text { x }2&32-28\\
27-32K&10-6\\31-26&28-24\\
26\text { x }19\text { x }28&6-1K \end {array}$$ and it seems clear that Black can let Red come to him, capture all the men, and king them all.  Red has space to shuffle his king when needed.  It wasn't hard to find.